# undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Can someone help me? I keep getting the error (See title).

I know there are a lot of people asking this question before in StackOverflow. I read their answers but when I paste the solution, I still keep hiting this error.

Below are the code.

Thank you very much.

```
//Jimmy code
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Merchant2 } from "./../Merchant2/Merchant2";

export class Login extends React.Component{

    constructor(prop) {

        super(prop);

        Navigation.events().bindComponent(this);

        this.state = {
          userName: "",
          password: "",
          isVerify: false
        };

         this.onPress=this.onPress.bind(this);

    }

    onPress = () => {

        //const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        navigate('Page2');

        alert(1)
    }

     render() {


      navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Results',
      };

        return (
                    <View style={[styles.formFooter]}>
                        <TouchableHighlight style={[commonStyles.alignItemsCenter, styles.loginBtn]}
                                            activeOpacity={1}
                                            underlayColor={'#cdcdcf'}
                                            onPress={this.onPress.bind(this)}
                        >

        );
    };
}

const App = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Merchant2 },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: Why its commented `//const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;`

Comment: Hi, I still face the problem if I comment these 3 lines.
 const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
  navigate('Page2');
  alert(1)

Comment: the navigation prop is passed into every screen component...so here its available only in your `Merchant2` so if you want it in `Login` then do like `<Login nav={this.props.navigation}/>`...

Answer (score 0):

A few things here:

- You should use methods with names different than the native ones such as 'onPress'
- If you don't have a navigation props, it's simply because you never references it in your stack navigation. All items who's view is specified in a navigation object should have a navigation props.
- `navigationOptions` should be tagged `static` if you define it in your component or like `Login.navigationOptions`. Also, if you want to add navigation options from the action of elements you create in your navigation options, you can do this like (in your component) : `static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({your navigation options here})`